# Dexador No OpSSL version number

Tags: web-scraping, lisp, common-lisp

I am having issues with the Dexador library (and same issue with the Drakma library) when attempting to webscrape. They work fine with HTTP requests, but I receive an error when working with HTTPS requests. Here is an example of the basic get request that I sent:

```
(defvar *url* "https://www.amazon.com/")
(defvar *request* (dex:get *url*))
```

Then I receive this backtrace:

```
No OpenSSL version number could be determined, both SSLeay and OpenSSL_version_num failed.
```

So i'm assuming something may be wrong with the OpenSSL library, but i'm not 100% sure what's going on. I achieved the request successfully on my windows machine from the command line, and OpenSSL works fine on my Windows 10 machine, but not in Common Lisp.

One solution that I saw was to set the keyword argument insecure to true:

```
(defvar *request* (dex:get *url* :insecure t))
```

But this does not work and a receive the same error. When I attempted to scrape an http website the request was successful:

```
(defvar *request* (dex:get "http://paulgraham.com"))
```

I am wondering if anyone else has had this problem and if there are any solutions that anyone has found. I do not know if this is an issue with Windows 10, a dependency library, or something else.

This works fine from the command line with:

```
curl -v "https://www.amazon.com"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that my version of OpenSSL was too new. CL+SSL is a dependency of Dexador, and CL+SSL wants the 1.0.1 version, and it wants the 32-bit version of OpenSSL specifically. After playing around with various versions, that seemed to fix the problem.